# How to handle 404 URI error in UWP Javascript Hosted web app Without WinJS

Tags: javascript, uwp, winjs

- How to handle 404 URI (Not included in appxManifest->Content URI
  section) in UWP app.
- If i add URI domain name in
  appxManifest->Content URI section then msapp-error.html will take
  care. other wise there is no action in App.

**NOTE:** I am not using WinJS.

Comment: First, you would have to add an Application Content URI Rules (ACURs) for your start page and any web resources utilized by that page. Then, I suggested that you need to debug your app in visual studio. When the app is running in the foreground, please press 'F12', it will open Microsoft Edge Developer Tools, in the console, please check if there're some errors .

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thanks for reply, My questions is to handle URI's which have HTTP status 404. And these URI's will come dynamically from another source. Where we don't add these domains in appxManifest->Content URI section. And i am using below code to redirect.`window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');`. App won't find this domain in appxManifest->ContentURI section. So it won't redirect to new location. App will stay on same page, at this scenario how can i handle errors, like forcefully terminate app or show message popup. Thanks.

Comment: When you get these dynamic URIs, how did access these URIs? By using javascript code to navigate? Or clicking a `<a/>` tag to redirect? Or other someting?

Comment: Yes by XHR request APP will get some links in JSON response. Based on some condition APP will redirect to specific URL's. So here I want to validate.

Comment: Is there any way to find the current hosted WebAPP start URL from JavaScript.

Comment: There's no such a way. The original intention of UWP (JS) design was designed for SinglePageApplication.